# error after compiling opencv2.4.3 on ios

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, xcode4.5

I have been facing the problems below when compiling an application on xcode for iOS after using the framework 2.4.3 from official opencv.org. Any clues?

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Anas/Downloads/ocr-text-extraction-master  /n/trunk/StaticImagesFaceDetectionSample/../../ocv.build/ios'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const", referenced from:
  cv::CascadeClassifier::Data::read(cv::FileNode const&) in opencv2(cascadedetect.o)
 ...
 ...

 ...

 cv::Exception::formatMessage() in opencv2(system.o)
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the universal iOS framework provided by OpenCV?

If not, I strongly suggest you to use it: [OpenCV for iOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.3/opencv2.framework.zip/download). Just download it, drop it into your iOS project and add import it.

You can also add this inside your `myApp-Prefix.pch` to import OpenCV in every C++ compatible source file (`.mm`, `.cpp`):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

**EDIT**

Also make sure that `opencv2.framework` is added to the target you're building. To add it to the target, open up the right side menu in Xcode (Utilities) while `opencv2.framework` is selected. There is a dropdown in the File Inspector called "Target Membership". If you select that, it will add the framework to the target.

**EDIT 2**

Another thing to make sure is importing the right headers to use `cv::CascadeClassifier`:

```
#import <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#import <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
```

Comment: Yes I am using the offical OpenCV for iOS. I did all what you said but I keep getting this problem.

Comment: I just redownloaded the precompiled version and it suddenly worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue has a very simple solution that tripped me up for hours as well. The fix is to make sure the View Controller or whatever iOS view is using the Open CV library is a **.MM** file and not a .M file. This will cause the file to be treated as a C++ file (which causes the following pre-compiled header directive to kick in and all linker errors will disappear.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```